# Are fully cured Polyjet parts safe to sand?

Tags: safety, polyjet-printer, toxicity

I work with poly-jet printed parts, more specifically, Stratasys objet pro, printed in Vero Black.
The parts are always fully cured before taken off the bed.

We are sometimes required to sand these printed parts down once support material is removed.
Is the dust given off during sanding (with sand paper or a Dremel tool) harmful similar to uncured material? can the dust given off whilst sanding still be carcinogenic if you breathe it in? or the fact that the material is cured makes it safe?

Just to add, it's only a few instances I've sanded to the point lots of particles are given off, usually its just a quick dash on the sandpaper.

Comment: Do you have an MSDS for the material? It would more than likely have the information you are seeking.

Comment: I have found one for Vero Black, though it is not clear if the measures recommended are for the material pre or post curing:                                                        https://protouk.com/3d-printing-data/MSDS-Vero-black-plus-SDS-06142_F_EN_AGHS_RGD875.pdf

Comment: It may be quicker to contact the manufacturer than wait for a random person to come across this question to give you the answer.